# Book on Non-Linear dynamics

Tags: resource-recommendations, education, non-linear-systems, complex-systems

I am currently planning on self studying Non-linear dynamics, with an intention of developing a decent idea about it and see how its applied. I don't want to be too rigorous in my dealing with the subject right now.  I have just completed my first year as an MSc Physics student, so what are the books that would be good, at this level.

Answer (score 0):

Strogatz's [Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0738204536) is a very friendly introduction to the subject, and is written in a very intuitive way. Personally I like the fact that gives you a very broad idea of the subject, without going into many unnecessary details. For a first approach to NL dynamics I strongly recommend this book.

If you are motivated by the subject and want to delve into the problems that make it fascinating, you can try [The Chaos Book](http://chaosbook.org/). This is an open resource written by [Cvitanovic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predrag_Cvitanovi%C4%87), one of the greatest in the field. You can approach this book in many different ways, is a good reference book, it is also great book for medium/advanced readers, but the amazing part is that you can get a lot from it if you are just a beginner. If you decide to go for this book, I strongly recommend to solve the problems!